# While loop does not execute as expected

Tags: python

so I just started learning python like today in the morning, and I decided to make a timer, and below is my code

```
while True:
    import time 
#=========================================================================================
    true=0
    while (true==0):
        a=int(input("how many minutes? "))
        if a>59 or a<0:
            print("please type a number between 0 and 60")
            true=0
        else:
            true=1
#==========================================================================================
    while (true==1):
        b=int(input("how many seconds? "))
        if b>59 or b<0:
            print("please type a number between 0 and 60")
            true=1
        else:
            true=2
#====================displaying the minutes and seconds====================================================================       
    while (true==2):    
        timen = 60*a + b
        while timen > 0:
            sec=int(timen%60)
        min=timen-timen%60
        finmin=int(min/60)
        print(str(finmin) + ':'+str(sec))
        time.sleep(1)
        timen = timen - 1
        true=3
#====================the looping mechanism====================================================================       
    while (true==3):
        c=input("time's up, press \"a\" start a new timer, press anything other key to exit this program.")
        if c!="a":
            break
```

that was my code, and I don't know which part of it doesn't work, because the output just stops at the photo. the program stops here, I am new to python and it is probably some stupid mistake that noobs make, but is anybody available to offer some help please?:

```
Welcome to the timer.
how many minutes? 5
how many seconds? 9
```

[my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w44mC.png)

Comment: In your loop `while timen > 0`, what do you expect would cause it to complete if the condition is true the first time?

Comment: `sec=int(timen%60)` never updates `timen`, which is what the loop depends on

Comment: Actually it looks like an indentation problem. Everything up to and including your `timen = timen - 1` statement needs to be indented so that it is inside the inner loop.

Comment: Though separately the `break` at the end won't work - get rid of the `while true == 3` and then it will break from the main `while True` loop instead.

Comment: wait I don't understand, the indentation is correct isn't it?

Comment: o nevermind, THANK YOU SO MUCH